# verifying Asymptotic Distributions using simulation methods

Tags: simulation, asymptotics

I've created 10 thousand simulated time series with sample size $T = 200$, simulated with a given autoregressive parameter ($\theta_0$ = 0.3) and for each I've estimated the autoregressive parameter from the data.

I want to look at the distribution of $\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0), $ which should be Normally distributed asymptotically speaking.

If I look at $\frac{\sqrt{T}(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0)}{\hat{\sigma}}$ it should be $N(0, 1)$ distributed , where  $\hat{\sigma}$ is the an estimate of the standard error of the parameter.

I am not sure if I'm doing something wrong but when I multiply $\frac{(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0)}{\hat{\sigma}}$
by $\sqrt{T}$ the variance of the resulting distribution is equal to $\sqrt{T}.$

NOTE: I am using the standard deviation of the 10k samples as $\hat{\sigma}, $ is that correct?

If I do not multiply by $\sqrt{T}$ the standard deviation is 1.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: Although (because you don't explain what your symbols refer to) it's unclear what you're doing, it appears that by "$\hat\sigma$" you need a standard error of some kind of parameter estimate and it's unlikely that would be correctly estimated by the SD of a large number of samples, regardless what a "sample" might refer to.  Could you clarify your terms and be more explicit about the calculations you are performing?

Comment: I clarified that sigma_hat was intended to be the standard error of the parameter in question. I think you answered my question: I need to get use an estimate of the the standard error of the estimator, and the standard deviation of the 10k coefficient estimates is not likely to be a good estimator of the parameter's standard error.

Comment: So...is this closed forever? I can post a new version if it is.